# how can I get my EntityAdapter to automatically load its data when a selector that needs it is used?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a Slice defined as such:

```js
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";
import { createEntityAdapter, EntityState } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Project } from "./project";

const projectAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Project>({
  selectId: (project) => project.id,
});
const initialState = projectAdapter.getInitialState();

export const projectsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProjects: builder.query<EntityState<Project>, void>({
      query: () => `api/projects`,
      keepUnusedDataFor: 30,
      transformResponse: (projects: Project[], meta) => {
        return projectAdapter.setAll(initialState, projects as Project[]);
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetProjectsQuery } = projectsApiSlice;

export const selectAllProjects = projectAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll;

export default projectsApiSlice.reducer;
```

In my react component, I tried using my selector like this:

```js
  let projects = useSelector(selectAllProjects);
```

But unfortunately projects is always null and my api/projects endpoint is never called, so what I ended up doing is this :

```js
const { data: projectsEntity } = useGetProjectsQuery();

if (!projectsEntity) return <div></div>;

let projects = selectAllProjects(projectsEntity);
```

I feel like I'm missing a piece of the puzzle. Is there a recommended way to automatically execute the relevant query when a selector is used?

Answer (score 0):

After the component calling `useGetProjectsQuery` finishes rendering, it should immediately start a network request.

Are you 100% sure that's not the case?

Generally, all your code here seems okay.

The only thing I could think of would be if you use a non-standard `baseQuery` that doesn't do requests.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clearly worded : if I use useGetProjectsQuery, everything is fine. What I would like to do is use my selectAllProjects selector, and have it automatically execute the underlying query (eg useGetProjectsQuery)

Comment: That's not possible. A selector is never allowed to have any side effects. That's what the hooks are for.

Comment: ahh; no side effects, obviously! Thank you for taking the time :)

Comment: You could use the selector inside of the `useQuery` with the `selectFromResult` option, if that makes you happy ;)